# How to reference the image from the xml?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This is the oncreate from my application.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
    //ImageView img = (ImageView)controlInflater.
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl 
        = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

}
```

control.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
        >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

how to reference the ImageView in control.xml from java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
ImageView img =(ImageView) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.img);
```

use this to get reference to imageView.

Answer (score 1):

There is a findViewById method in View as well:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)viewControl.findViewById(R.id.img)
```